# How to find if folder exists in sharepoint online document library using MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I would like to create files under a folder in sharepoint library if that specific folder exists. Else I will create a folder and create files. I would like to do this using MS FLOW. ANy help or ideas on this are highly appreciated.

I tried the following method

1. Created a FLOW on an item created event.
2. created a rest api GET request for the document library with the folder name as a variable
3. then create a decision tree after this which will check if the value returned from rest is empty or not.

[image]

The problem is its continuously retrying in the rest api step. Could someone tell me how to do this more efficiently.

Comment: is flow retrying? or just end up with an error?

Answer (score 0):

We can use create folder action with in the flow, based on output value true/false we can check folder existed or not with in the document library.

To create folder with in the document library check below link.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/MS-Flow-Create-new-folder-action/ba-p/355632